# What is the relationship between a boost transformation and a high energy limit?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, scattering-cross-section

S-matrix element is calculated by a following formula,
$$S_{\beta \alpha}=\langle \beta_{in}|U(+\infty,-\infty)|\alpha_{in}\rangle.$$
The time-evolution operator $U(+\infty,-\infty)$ is
$$U(+\infty,-\infty)=T\exp\Big(i\int^\infty_{-\infty}d^4x\ \mathcal{L}_I( \phi_{in}(x))\Big).$$
On the other hand, according to [these slides](https://www.ipht.fr/Pisp/francois.gelis/Physics/2007-florianopolis2.pdf), the scattering amplitude under the eikonal limit is defined by
$$S_{\beta \alpha}\equiv\lim_{\omega\rightarrow+\infty}\langle \beta_{in}|e^{-i\omega K^3}U(+\infty,-\infty) e^{i\omega K^3} |\alpha_{in}\rangle,$$
where $K^3$ is the generator of Lorentz boosts in the +z direction.

My question is, why is the Eikonal limit, a kind of high energy limit, related to the Lorentz boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start at the classical level. Say that in frame 1, a point particle is moving slowly in the $x$ direction. Frame 2, is related to frame 1 by a big boost in the $z$ direction. What is the particle doing in frame 2? It is still moving slowly in the $x$ direction, but it also has a huge momentum in the $z$ direction. So a physicist in frame 2 can safely take the approximation that the particle is a relativistic particle moving along the $z$ direction.

That is more or less what is going on in the last formula of yours. One of the key things to keep in mind is that transition probabilities are Lorentz scalars, so you can compute them in any inertial frame. So the first formula and the last formula give exactly the same probabilities---for any *finite* value of $\omega$. But when you take the limit, you are making a certain approximation.